# Get temporised operations without draw() timing errors

Tags: java, processing

I try to get an accurate clock within Processing sketch without the timing caused by the `draw()` function.

I actually use `System.nanoTime()` from Java instead `mills()` to get nano seconds, I recall the clock inside void draw to initialize it.

I'd like to know how to get an independent clock from `draw()` to send some messages without the `draw()` function timing.

I need it for a musical sequencer inside android, i need it totally accurate.

This is my situation:

```
long lasttimecheck;
long timeinterval;

void setup() {
  lasttimecheck = System.nanoTime();
  //step duration 
  timeinterval  = 125000000L;
}

void clock(){
  if (System.nanoTime() > lasttimecheck + timeinterval) {
    lasttimecheck = System.nanoTime();
    println("yeah" +  lasttimecheck);
  }

}
void draw() {
clock();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing provides an easy threading implementation: You can simply call *thread("clock");* in *setup()* without worrying about any threading boilerplate code.

---

Alternatively, as 125000000ns = 0.125s = 8 times per second, you could set the framerate to 64 in *setup()* with:

```
frameRate(64)
```

...and do whatever you're intending *clock()* to trigger every eighth frame by adding the following within the *draw()* loop:

```
if (frameCount % 8 == 0) {do();}
```

At 64fps, every eighth frame occurs at 0.125s increments.

Comment: Thanks @micycle this might be the solution!

Comment: Hi @micylce i tried to recall clock void with thread("clock") inside setup but it don't want to print anything in the consolle but i also never get some errors. It work into draw() but the frequency is related to the framerate yet. The thread is sure what i need to dynamically change the clock speed during the program execution without care about the clock time related to the frame rate proportion, do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @MassimoVantaggio Have you surrounded the code in clock() with a while (true)? If not, it'll only run once (and won't print because the if statement's condition isn't met at the start of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your goal is (or why the `draw()` function doesn't work for that goal), but you could create your own thread and perform your own timing. Something like this:

```
void setup(){
  new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      while(true){
        doTheThing();
        Thread.sleep(1); //sleep for 1 ms
      }
    }
  }.start();
}
```

This is just a simple example, and threading (aka concurrency) is an advanced topic with a lot of complicated stuff to consider. So if I were you I'd take a step back and try to work within the confines of the regular `draw()` loop instead of taking on threading yourself.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, draw() refresh it self every frame which default is 60hz. i think that if i recall the void clock from draw it will be not accurate, is this correct? However your solution seems to feet for me, but i need to change during the execution the clock time, so i can't do it in void setup.

Comment: @MassimoVantaggio Please research threading / concurrency. The thread continues to run even after the `setup()` function completes.

Comment: I just try to copy it inside Processing and i got an error on Thread.sleep : Unhandled exception type InterruptedException

Comment: @MassimoVantaggio Right, my code was just an example. You're going to have to do some more research to get it working the way you want. I'd start by googling that error if I were you.